# kubernetes deploy a pod with versioned secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I want to use k8s secret but I have many question.

1. I updated a secret and I want to run just new image pods with this secret. Any pods can be down and New pod can be start with this new secret before I don't apply new image. How can I run old image with old secret?
2. I need rollback a deployment image. I want rollback secret too. How can I rollback a secret?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "before I don't apply new image"?

Comment: Hi Fritz, I think, One pod down. New pod will start old image and new secret. I think its a problem because my new configuration can not run old image code

Comment: Are your secrets mounted as volumes or as environment variables?

Comment: I used mounted volume

Comment: If you switch to mounting as env, this wont be updated in running pods to do more or less what you want. Otherwise, I would switch to using two separate deployments.